# Vue.js define lodash requires "this._"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, lodash

I want to define lodash globally and use it without having to write 'this._.func()' in my scripts

```
Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, "_", { value: _ });
```

^ this is the best practice example I've found, but again..this._.func() is SO ANNOYING....couldn't find anything online....

Comment: _"^ this is the best practice example I've found"_ really? That is awful for so many reasons.

Comment: `window._ = _` instead?

Comment: @JaromandaX do I define it in my main js?

Comment: @AluanHaddad that's such an helpful response..how about you enlighten me?...

Comment: where ever you load lodash - i.e. where `_` is defined

Comment: Don't change code you don't control for the sake of convenience because you have no idea how your code may break in the future. It's will confuse anyone who works with you. You'll have to explain it to everyone.

Comment: That's why it was a comment not an answer.